# WPF Scrollviewer not visible inside Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism

WPF Scrollviewer not visible inside Usercontrol.

I am using PRISM pattern.

I have a scrollviewer inside usercontrol and the scrollviewer contains a stackpanel.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="SomeView"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"        
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"         
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"         
      mc:Ignorable="d" >

     <UserControl.Resources>        
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>        
     </UserControl.Resources>

     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  
     <StackPanel>     
<TextBlock Text="Initialize" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">     
 <Label Content="Left"/>     

 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LeftComboItems}"  SelectedItem="{Binding LeftSelectedItem}" />　
 <Label Content="Right"/>     
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RightComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding RightSelectedItem}"/>     
 <Label/>    

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>     
 </StackPanel>     
 <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">   

 <Grid>
```

Skipping column definitions

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">     
 <Label Content="Left"  />     
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LeftDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Column="2" >     
 <DataGrid.Columns>     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />     
 </DataGrid.Columns>     
 </DataGrid>     
 </StackPanel>  

 <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">   
 <Label Content="Left Grid" />     
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RightDataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >


 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding id}" />     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>     

 </DataGrid>
 </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel> 
 </Grid>    
     </StackPanel>        
     </ScrollViewer>
```

LeftComboItems, RightComboItems are Observable Collections of type string.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer won't show up since you only have an empty stack panel. Try adding some items that has a width or height and you should see the scroll viewer.